# Print year after title addon

Tags: biblatex, xetex, authoryear

The following MWE produces a bibliography entry as shown in the image below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@book{qingshi1998,
    date = {1998},
    title = {Qingshi gao},
    titleaddon = {清史稿},
    location = {Beijing},
    publisher = {Zhonghua}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literature}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The year is printed after the title and before the title addon.
The problem here seems to be that there is no author specified: when I add a fictitious author, the date is correctly printed after the author and before the title.

According to the biblatex manual, an author is required for `book` type entries.
However, I tried other entry types that don’t require an author and obtained the same result.

How can I keep the title and title addon in separate data fields, omit the author, but still have the year printed after the title addon?

Comment: Please make a short, but compilable test document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field `author` (or any other field defined as label) is empty, the standard styles of `biblatex` use another field as `label` in the bibliography. In case of the `authoryear` style its `shorttitle` or, if that is empty too, simply `title`.

If you redefine the macro in a way that it uses `title` and `titleaddon`, you get the wanted result. As delimiter I chose a dot, but you can adjust it with biblatexs delimiter commands. I don't know if you use the `shorttitle` field. If not, it's OK this way. If you use it, but don't want it to get printed as label, you have to edit the particular condition.

Here your adapted MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{literature.bib}
@book{qingshi1998,
    date = {1998},
    title = {Qingshi gao},
    titleaddon = {清史稿},
    location = {Beijing},
    publisher = {Zhonghua}
}

@book{qingshi1999,
    date = {1999},
    title = {Qingshi gao},
    shorttitle = {Gao},
    titleaddon = {清史稿},
    location = {Beijing},
    publisher = {Zhonghua}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{literature}
\renewbibmacro*{labeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {\iffieldundef{titleaddon}{%
            \printfield{title}%
            \clearfield{title}%
            }{%
            \printfield{title}\addperiod\space\printfield[title]{titleaddon}%
            \clearfield{title}\clearfield{titleaddon}}
        }
       {\printfield[title]{shorttitle}
        }}
    {\printfield{label}}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1} Uncomment if you want title NOT in italics
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

There are more possibilities to adapt the use of fields as `label` for your bibliography. E.g. for other `entrtypes` etc. For the one you posted this solution works fine. If you need something more sophisticated, you can refine your question.

**Edit:** I updated the code a little bit. Now, it shows your regular example and one with a `shorttitle` (which, in this case, produces no sense in Chinese, I guess; apologise for that). Also, if the `titleaddon` is used as part of the label, it now is formatted the same way as `title` to keep it coherent. You could turn of emphasised titles by redefining it via `\DeclareFieldFormat`. To test it, just uncomment the particular command at the bottom of the praeambel and look how the Chinese font also changes its shape.

Comment: Usually punctuation commands like `\adddot\addspace` should not appear outside a `\setunit` or similar command in a bibmacro. Otherwise we bypass the punctuation buffer and may cause unwanted punctuation (though `biblatex` has other emergency features to prevent double punctuation, so the issue might not always present itself clearly). Also `\adddot` adds a dot, which (at least in `biblatex` speak) signifies the end of an abbreviation. ...

Comment: ... Usually one would use `\addperiod` for a period/full stop. (The usual idiom is `\addperiod\space`, since the clean-up of `\addspace` is not needed after another `\add...`.)

Comment: The is a missing `%` after `\iffieldundef{titleaddon}{`, which would cause undesirable space if `biblatex` did not counter it. Still, it's better to add the space than to rely on secondary `biblatex` features. (Like with bare punctuation.)

Comment: Added your edits. Thanks @moewe, again something learned ;). Biblatex has so many minor commands, sometimes you get lost...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven’t had time to check it out but will do and accept if it works.

Comment: No problem. Take your time :)